# How to create typed template literals from enums in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Are there any way to let TS know that `param` is not just `string` but type `RoleWithTier` (except for explicit `as` cast)?

```
enum Role {
    USER = 'user',
    ADMIN = 'admin'
}

enum Tier {
    ENTRY = 1,
    MAXIMUM = 10
} 

type RoleWithTier = `${Role}.${Tier}`


const param = `${Role.USER}.${Tier.ENTRY}`

const selectAction = (rwt: RoleWithTier) {
    // do stuff
}

selectAction(param) // Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"user.1" | "user.10" | "admin.1" | "admin.10"'.(2345)
```

[Link to TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBASg9gG2FA3gKCpqBVAygURigF4oByMAZ2ACcyAaDLAQQBEBZASQDkTyBDACYQAliDJoAvmjShIUACojaqJpnzcFMAJp8AjIyxR2zABqd22dvoAMUqDIAuATwAOyeEgDqIxwAslFVIAAwASFE9gSQA6cMCaSWCZNABjOBBKRyhXfhp%20aBDwyOi8Qkk45RpojS1tRJk0jKzqJBTHZjaRdL4AChoAd0cALlhEYB9-eIBKVSMAejmoQTgoTLAAM3WpGRbgNo7HLpAenLyIKaA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The moment you declare `param`, its type is inferred as `string` and the subsequent call won't change that. Either pass the template string directly:

```js
selectAction(`${Role.USER}.${Tier.ENTRY}`); // ok
```

Or add a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```js
const param = `${Role.USER}.${Tier.ENTRY}` as const;
```

Comment: `as const` is something I was looking  for!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can just type the `param` variable normally:

```
const param: RoleWithTier = `${Role.USER}.${Tier.ENTRY}`;
```

Also you're missing the `.` in the param value

Comment: Thank you! Looks like an option as well as using `as const`